# strsep() usage and its alternative

Tags: c, string, tokenize, strsep

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {

char *slogan = "together{kaliya} [namak]";
char *slow_gun = strdup(slogan);

char *token = strsep(&slow_gun, "{");

printf ("\n slow_gun: %s\n token: %s\n", slow_gun, token);

return 0;
}
```

when I execute it:

```
$ cc -o try try_strsep.c
$ ./try

 slow_gun: kaliya} [namak]
 token: together
```

But when, I change the char *slogan to:

```
char *slogan = "kalia} [namak]";
```

and execute the same program:

```
$ vi try_strsep.c 
$ cc -o try try_strsep.c
$ ./try

 slow_gun: (null)
 token: kalia} [namak]
```

My **Question** is, so when I use strsep() and input string does not have the pattern I am looking for, the return of strsep() is **wrong**. The only way I can validate whether strsep() could not find the pattern is to check `if (slow_gun == NUll)`.

If I have `char *slogan = "together{"` then `strsep` would successfully return `token` but returns `slow_gun` to blank (not `null`)

```
$ cc -o try try_strsep.c
$ ./try

 slow_gun: 
 token: together
```

Is there a way I could avoid this IF check and rely on the function to return me the substr and if its not there, return `NULL`?

Comment: You need to `free` the string returned by `strdup`

Comment: @Praetorian: You had me into tears. I agree to you but is that going to help me with my question?

Comment: Helping someone avoid memory leaks always helps :-) My answer below should help you with your question.

Comment: You made me think of this talk http://goo.gl/ks0Oe :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No, there's no way to avoid the check `slow_gun == NULL`. [Here's a description](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strsep) of `strsep`'s behavior:

```
char *strsep(char **stringp, const char *delim);
```

> **DESCRIPTION**
> If `*stringp` is `NULL`, the `strsep()` function returns `NULL` and does nothing else. Otherwise, this function finds the first token in the string `*stringp`, where tokens are delimited by symbols in the string `delim`. This token is terminated by overwriting the delimiter with a null byte (`'\0'`) and `*stringp` is updated to point past the token. In case no delimiter was found, the token is taken to be the entire string `*stringp`, and `*stringp` is made `NULL`.
>
> **RETURN VALUE**
> The `strsep()` function returns a pointer to the token, that is, it returns the original value of `*stringp`.

So, if no match is found `strsep` returns a pointer to the original string and sets the `slow_gun` input to NULL.

If the delimiter is the last character in the string, that character is overwritten by '\0' and `slow_gun` is set to the following character, which happens to be the '\0' terminating the original string. This is why print statement prints an empty string.

**NOTE** You're using `strdup` incorrectly, the caller is responsible for calling `free` on the pointer returned by that function.

Answer (score 7):

> > the return of strsep() is wrong

That's not right.  `strsep()` returns the first token it finds - the beginning of the string is by definition the first token.  It's just that no delimiter has been found to terminate the token in this case (so the remainder of the string is the token).

`strsep()` is not intended to be used to 'find a pattern' - it's used to separate tokens based on a set of delimiters.  If you want to find a character, use `strchr()` or `strpbrk()`.

Answer (score 2):

strsep is behaving correctly - from the [man page](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/strsep/):

> The `strsep()` function locates, in the string referenced by `*stringp`,
>   the first occurrence of any character in the string delim (or the
>   terminating `\0` character) and replaces it with a `\0`.  The location of the
>   next character after the delimiter character (or `NULL`, if the end of
>   the string was reached) is stored in `*stringp`.  The original value of
>   `*stringp` is returned.

The second case *is* correct - since the delimeter isn't found the first parameter is set to point at `NULL` and the original string is returned.  As you say, you need to check for `if (slow_gun == NUll)` to detect this.

(incidentally, that's a horribly confusing choice of variable names).